# Unwanted paddings or margin in ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am brand new to android to android development and just playing around with xmls for building layouts. I wrote the following code stuffs for printing a hello ubuntu and inserting an image in it. But the Image seems to have a unwanted upper and bottom padding or margin (not sure what it's called) which looks wierd. Please anyone help me removing it. Here is my code :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="Hello Ubuntu (16.06LTS)"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/Ubuntu"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot here(see the preiew on right side):

[image: 1]

Comment: Check your `Ubuntu` named images. Does it have extra space ?

Comment: Could you add images for how it actually looks and how you want it to be

Comment: plz provide screen image

Comment: Add ScaleType to ImageView  .centerInside

Comment: uploaded the screenshot

Answer (score 5):

those extra padding is autogenerated since the android would try to get the original aspect ratio. please try below

```
scaletype = "fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `android:scaleType` (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType)).
This will allow you to tell the view how to react if the image does not have the exact size of the view.

Comment: Have you tried to sel 'centerCrop' ? And also according to your screenshot, it looks like te image have wihte bodrder. Maybe you could try to set a background color to the image view to see if the image is filling all the imzgr view or not ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`,

it works for me.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="Hello Ubuntu (16.06LTS)"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/asd"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a margin above the imageview but it is not the part of imageview. It is actually because of margin applied to the textview above the imageview. You can do the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#00ffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Hello Ubuntu (16.06LTS)"
    android:background="#000000"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="371dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    />
```

**EDIT -** 
In your above code, you have applied Margin to all the sides of the view. (`android:layout_margin="8dp`")
This gives the margin to the view from all the 4 sides including the bottom one, which appears as the imageview's top margin.

Hence, what you need to do is to apply margin to the view side by side by changing 
    `android:layout_margin="8dp"`
to

`android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  android:layout_marginUpper="8dp"`

**EDIT 2 -** 
Make sure you have 0 padding and 0 margin in the parent (root) container.

Comment: Please elaborate what you changed and why